# How to sample from a defined probability region of a Multi-Variate Normal Distribution using PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, statistics, computer-vision, gaussian

Is there a straightforward way to sample from a multivariate normal distribution in PyTorch and only keep the samples that are in a defined low-probability region (e.g. P(x) < 5 %)?

Concrete example:
I have a batch of representation tensors as an output of a ResNet with a size of `(batch_size, feature_size)`.

I can then generate the mean vector `prototype` with `size = (1, feature_size)` of those representations, and the corresponding empirical `cov` matrix with `size = (feature_size, feature_size)`. From my understanding I can use PyTorchs `distributions` package to sample from the multivariate normal distribution, defined by `prototype` and `cov` like so:

```
from torch.distributions.multivariate_normal import MultivariateNormal
import torch.nn as nn

dist = MultivariateNormal(prototype, covariance_matrix = cov)
samples = dist.sample(torch.Size([10000]))
```

I'd like to know how to determine the probability region that a sample belongs to, i.e., I only want to keep samples with low probability. I am aware that there is `dist.log_prob(value)`. However, I'm having a hard time gaining an intuition from that. The outputs don't seem to make a lot of sense. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'd be interested in knowing an answer too.